# Typescript: Optional property based on generic

Tags: typescript, generics, undefined

I have a TypeScript type definition like this:

```
export type MyConfig<
    T extends MyObject = MyObject,
    R extends MyRegistry|undefined = undefined,
> = {
    title: string | null,
    objects: T[],
    registry: R,
};
```

By default, the registry field should be optional (undefined). But if you specify the type param, you must provide it.

But I have a problem using this, when the R generic param is set to undefined:

```
const a: MyConfig = { title: null, objects: [] }; // Doesn't work: Property 'registry' is missing but required
const b: MyConfig<MyObject, MyRegistry> = { title: null, objects: [], registry: {} }; // works ok
const c: MyConfig<MyObject, undefined> = { title: null, objects: [], registry: undefined }; // works ok
const d: MyConfig<MyObject, MyRegistry|undefined> = { title: null, objects: [], registry: undefined }; // works ok
```

How can I make the type definition of MyConfig accept the missing 'registry' property (like in example 'a')?

I have tried this, but then, the examples where 'registry' is required dont work anymore:

```
export type MyConfig<
    T extends MyObject = MyObject,
    R extends MyRegistry|undefined = undefined,
> = {
    title: string | null,
    objects: T[],
    registry?: R, // <-- I have tried marking it as optional.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional type for the `registry` and mark it as `never` when you don't want it !

```
export type MyConfig<
  T extends MyObject = MyObject,
  R extends MyRegistry | undefined = undefined,
> = {
  title: string | null,
  objects: T[],
} & (R extends undefined ? { registry?: never } : { registry: R });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKBvKwAlsADYQBcUAzsAE6EB2A5lAD5QMCuJJANFAHsU6YFUoBBWrQCGIADzSGIAHxQAvgChQkWCABKEJoRq0Q2POo0aIADzADambdDgBhAQwBmhJnI1QoABUoW2AIBgATKl0kVAxzOFiRXn8oPRCbMMjouAMjEzN2TkiIbwYICPNiiNLGCpTVHFxUolIKajpGFnYuHhSAoTjRSkCAbQBdFLUoADIoAAp00PCoqGra8sqAfgtaQ2M6EC3KcoA3CFp1KEp8PfzDynS1AEoAbis0DxooaUo3D28LCaBGIZBO3D4gmEGDEUAm6nenwY30QfxA7i8PjkiWhwH4uX2BUaFlaYI4EP4gxEsIm-DuB1MN2maleUAA9GyoAB3BwAa2iAl5GiR3zQaIxgOxCFx-HWZQqxPwpPavUhVJhlFpUHpBUocrqlRZ7M5PNo-MEQpFmAi4oBWJxQ3x%20kJhzYaxK8oiipBbXBfShQxpk21LsZ7pqnoRxu5fIFvKAA)